# Trying to create a bookmark for creating a table of contents but I am unable to create it .net Core

Tags: pdf, pdftron

I want to create a new pdf file by merging multiple files using PDFTron. But when I am trying to add a bookmarks like table of contents, Cover page etc. then I am unable to create it. As I have tried many code samples posted in the community and also from Samples that we can find out in Download section (https://dev.apryse.com/windows) but still I am unable to get the desired results. I am using PdfTron latest version

```
try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Starting boardpack/book files export.");

                var migrationSettingForMeetingPaqList = _resourcesQuery.GetMigrationSettingForMeetingsPaq(customerId)?.ToList() ?? new List<MigrationSettingMeetingPaq>();


                string lis = "demo:1702038740050:7cb966690300000000fd52298d2707380fe986b7e36356fc55460afaee";
                PDFNet.Initialize(lis);
                string directoryPath = fileDumpPath;
                using (PDFDoc mergedPdf = new PDFDoc())
                {
                    mergedPdf.InitSecurityHandler();
                    string fileExtension = string.Empty;
                    //string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.*");


                    foreach (var filePath in exportedBooks.Take(5))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (filePath.FileName != null)
                            {
                                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath.FileName).ToLower();
                            }
                            if (fileExtension == ".pdf" || fileExtension == ".pptx" || fileExtension == ".docx" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                            {
                                using (PDFDoc docToMerge = new PDFDoc(directoryPath + "\\" + filePath.FileName))
                                {


                                    if (fileExtension == ".pdf")
                                    {
                                        mergedPdf.InsertPages(mergedPdf.GetPageCount() + 1, docToMerge, 1, docToMerge.GetPageCount(), PDFDoc.InsertFlag.e_none);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        WordToPDFOptions options = new WordToPDFOptions();
                                        pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(docToMerge, filePath.FileUrl);

                                        //tempPdfDoc.InsertPages(tempPdfDoc.GetPageCount() + 1, tempPdfDoc, 1, tempPdfDoc.GetPageCount(), PDFDoc.InsertFlag.e_none);

                                        //string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(fileDumpPath, "merged_output23.pdf");
                                        //string outputDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(outputFilePath);
                                        //if (!Directory.Exists(outputDirectory))
                                        //{
                                        //    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDirectory);
                                        //}

                                        //// Save the PDF file
                                        //tempPdfDoc.Save(outputFilePath, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
                                        //ConvertToPdf(docToMerge, filePath, fileDumpPath);
                                        mergedPdf.InsertPages(mergedPdf.GetPageCount() + 1, docToMerge, 1, docToMerge.GetPageCount(), PDFDoc.InsertFlag.e_none);
                                    }
                                }

                                //else if (fileExtension == ".png")
                                //{
                                //    using (PDFDoc pdfdoc = new PDFDoc())
                                //    {
                                //        Console.WriteLine("Converting from XPS");

                                //        pdftron.PDF.Convert.FromXps(pdfdoc, filePath + "simple-xps.xps");
                                //        pdfdoc.Save(fileDumpPath + "xps2pdf v2.pdf", SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused);
                                //        // Console.WriteLine("Saved xps2pdf v2.pdf");
                                //    }
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error processing file {filePath}: {ex.Message}");
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        int pageIdx = 1;
                        int docPage = 0;
                        Bookmark bm = null;
                        int tocIdx = 0;
                        string debug = "";
                        string textValue = "";
                        var agendaPageCount = 0;
                        ElementBuilder eb = new ElementBuilder();
                        ElementWriter ew = new ElementWriter();
                        Element e = null;

                        if (migrationSettingForMeetingPaqList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var setting in migrationSettingForMeetingPaqList)
                            {
                                switch (setting.Name)
                                {
                                    case "Re-Create Existing Book":

                                        break;
                                    case "Cover Page":
                                        if (setting.IsSelected)
                                        {
                                            bm = pdftron.PDF.Bookmark.Create(mergedPdf, setting.Name);
                                            bm.SetAction(pdftron.PDF.Action.CreateGoto(pdftron.PDF.Destination.CreateFit(mergedPdf.GetPage(pageIdx))));
                                            mergedPdf.AddRootBookmark(bm);
                                            pageIdx++;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "Table of Contents":
                                        if (setting.IsSelected)
                                        {
                                            bm = pdftron.PDF.Bookmark.Create(mergedPdf, setting.Name);
                                            bm.SetAction(pdftron.PDF.Action.CreateGoto(pdftron.PDF.Destination.CreateFit(mergedPdf.GetPage(pageIdx))));
                                            mergedPdf.AddRootBookmark(bm);
                                            tocIdx = pageIdx;
                                            pageIdx++;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "Boardpack Agenda":
                                        if (setting.IsSelected)
                                        {
                                            debug = "Set Text Value";
                                            var meeting = migrationSettingForMeetingPaqList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Boardpack Minutes");
                                            if (meeting != null && meeting.IsSelected)
                                            {
                                                textValue = "Minutes";
                                            }

                                            debug = "Bookmark.Create";
                                            bm = pdftron.PDF.Bookmark.Create(mergedPdf, textValue);

                                            debug = "PDFDoc.GetPage " + pageIdx.ToString() + " of " + mergedPdf.GetPageCount().ToString();
                                            pdftron.PDF.Page pg = mergedPdf.GetPage(pageIdx);

                                            debug = "Destination.CreateFit to page " + pageIdx.ToString() + " of " + mergedPdf.GetPageCount().ToString();
                                            pdftron.PDF.Destination dest = pdftron.PDF.Destination.CreateFit(pg);

                                            debug = "Action.CreateGoto";
                                            pdftron.PDF.Action act = pdftron.PDF.Action.CreateGoto(dest);

                                            debug = "Bookmark.SetAction";
                                            bm.SetAction(act);

                                            debug = "PDFDoc.AddRootBookmark";
                                            mergedPdf.AddRootBookmark(bm);

                                            debug = "Up Page Count";
                                            pageIdx += agendaPageCount;

                                            docPage = pageIdx;
                                            var cnt = 0;
                                            foreach (var mpdoc in exportedBooks)
                                            {
                                                cnt++;
                                                if (cnt > 5) break;
                                                var extension = Path.GetExtension(mpdoc.FileName).ToLower();
                                                if (extension == ".pdf" || extension == ".pptx" || extension == ".docx" || extension == ".xlsx")
                                                {
                                                    textValue = mpdoc.FileName;
                                                    bm = pdftron.PDF.Bookmark.Create(mergedPdf, textValue);
                                                    bm.SetAction(pdftron.PDF.Action.CreateGoto(pdftron.PDF.Destination.CreateFit(mergedPdf.GetPage(docPage))));
                                                    mergedPdf.AddRootBookmark(bm);
                                                    PDFDoc doc = mergedPdf;
                                                    docPage += 1;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "Boardpack Minutes":

                                        break;
                                    case "PDF Meeting Docs":

                                        break;
                                    case "e-signature page":

                                        break;
                                    case "Doc Approval Detail":

                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            double pts = 10;
                            double ptsH = 4;


                            Element eH, eR;

                            pdftron.PDF.Page tocPage = mergedPdf.GetPage(tocIdx);

                            float fpts = System.Convert.ToSingle(pts);
                            float fptsH = System.Convert.ToSingle(ptsH);

                            //System.Drawing.Font sysFontBig = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies.SansSerif), fpts + 2, FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
                            //System.Drawing.Font sysFontReg = new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies.SansSerif), fpts, FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
                            System.Drawing.Font sysFontBig = new System.Drawing.Font("SansSerif", fpts + fptsH, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                            System.Drawing.Font sysFontReg = new System.Drawing.Font("SansSerif", fpts, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                            pdftron.PDF.Font pdfFontBld = pdftron.PDF.Font.Create(mergedPdf, sysFontBig.Name, "");
                            pdftron.PDF.Font pdfFontReg = pdftron.PDF.Font.Create(mergedPdf, sysFontReg.Name,"");


                            double lMargin = 72;
                            double rMargin = 72;
                            double tMargin = 50;
                            double bMargin = 72;
                            double tocTitleSpacing = 15;
                            double tocRowSpacing = 10;
                            double xPos = 0;
                            double yPos = 0;
                            double textLen = 0;
                            int numBM = 0;

                            bm = mergedPdf.GetFirstBookmark();
                            while (bm.IsValid())
                            {
                                numBM++;
                                bm = bm.GetNext();
                            }


                            eb.Reset();
                            eH = eb.CreateTextRun("Head", pdfFontBld, pts + ptsH);
                            eR = eb.CreateTextRun("Row", pdfFontReg, pts);

                            double pw = tocPage.GetPageWidth();
                            double ph = tocPage.GetPageHeight();

                            double tableSize = ph - tMargin - eH.GetGState().GetFontSize() - tocTitleSpacing - bMargin;
                            double rowSize = eR.GetGState().GetFontSize() + tocRowSpacing;
                            int rowsPerPage = (int)(tableSize / rowSize);
                            int tocPageCount = (int)(numBM / rowsPerPage);
                            if ((tocPageCount * rowsPerPage) < numBM)
                            {
                                tocPageCount++;
                            }
                            for (int i = 1; i < tocPageCount; i++)
                            {
                                Page p = mergedPdf.PageCreate();
                                if (mergedPdf.GetPageCount() < 2)
                                {
                                    mergedPdf.PagePushBack(p);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    mergedPdf.PageInsert(mergedPdf.GetPageIterator(tocIdx + 1), p);
                                }
                            }
                            //
                            // Create Table of Contents
                            //
                            bool newTocPage = true;
                            int curTocIdx = -1;
                            int curRowNum = 1;

                            bm = mergedPdf.GetFirstBookmark();
                            while (bm.IsValid())
                            {
                                if (newTocPage)
                                {
                                    curTocIdx++;
                                    tocPage = mergedPdf.GetPage(tocIdx + curTocIdx);
                                    ew.Begin(tocPage);
                                    eb.Reset();
                                    ew.WriteElement(eb.CreateTextBegin());
                                    yPos = ph - tMargin;
                                    if (curTocIdx == 0)
                                    {
                                        textValue = "Table of Contents";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        textValue = "Table of Contents (cont.)";
                                    }
                                    e = eb.CreateTextRun(textValue);
                                    e.GetGState().SetHorizontalScale(100);
                                    e.GetGState().SetCharSpacing(1.25);
                                    e.GetGState().SetTextRenderMode(GState.TextRenderingMode.e_fill_stroke_text);
                                    textLen = e.GetTextLength();
                                    xPos = (pw / 2) - (textLen / 2);
                                    e.SetTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, xPos, yPos);
                                    ew.WriteElement(e);
                                    yPos -= (eH.GetGState().GetFontSize() + tocTitleSpacing);
                                    curRowNum = 1;
                                    newTocPage = false;
                                    ew.WriteElement(eb.CreateTextEnd());
                                    ew.End();
                                }
                                ew.Begin(tocPage);
                                eb.Reset();
                                ew.WriteElement(eb.CreateTextBegin());
                                textValue = bm.GetTitle();
                                e = eb.CreateTextRun(textValue);
                                textLen = e.GetTextLength();
                                xPos = lMargin;
                                double max = pw - rMargin;
                                var tocInclPageNums = true;
                                if (tocInclPageNums) { max -= rMargin; }
                                while (xPos + textLen > max)
                                {
                                    textValue = textValue.Substring(0, textValue.Length - 1);
                                    e = eb.CreateTextRun(textValue + "...");
                                    textLen = e.GetTextLength();
                                }
                                e.SetTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, xPos, yPos);
                                ew.WriteElement(e);

                                pdftron.PDF.Destination bmDest = bm.GetAction().GetDest();
                                pdftron.PDF.Page bmPage = bmDest.GetPage();
                                int pageNum = bmPage.GetIndex();
                                if (tocInclPageNums == true)
                                {
                                    textValue = bmPage.GetIndex().ToString();
                                    e = eb.CreateTextRun(textValue);
                                    textLen = e.GetTextLength();
                                    xPos = pw - rMargin - textLen;
                                    e.SetTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, xPos, yPos);
                                    ew.WriteElement(e);
                                }
                                pdftron.PDF.Rect bmRect = new pdftron.PDF.Rect();
                                e.GetBBox(bmRect);
                                ew.WriteElement(eb.CreateTextEnd());
                                Obj stm = ew.End();

                                bmRect.x1 = lMargin;
                                bmRect.x2 = pw - rMargin;
                                pdftron.PDF.Annots.Link lnk = pdftron.PDF.Annots.Link.Create(mergedPdf, bmRect, bm.GetAction());
                                lnk.SetBorderStyle(new pdftron.PDF.Annot.BorderStyle(Annot.BorderStyle.Style.e_solid, 0));
                                tocPage.AnnotPushBack(lnk);

                                yPos -= (eR.GetGState().GetFontSize() + tocRowSpacing);
                                curRowNum++;
                                if (curRowNum > rowsPerPage)
                                {
                                    newTocPage = true;
                                }
                                bm = bm.GetNext();
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Generate Error(f):  " + ex.Message);
                        }
                        // Save the merged PDF
                        string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(fileDumpPath, "merged_output.pdf");
                        mergedPdf.Save(outputFilePath, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Merged PDF saved to: {outputFilePath}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error saving merged PDF: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
```

First I am merging multiple files, then I am trying to create the table of contents and Cover Page etc. But I have used multiple combinations of codes from official website as well but nothing is working for me.

I want to merge files from folder into PDF then need to create/add a Cover page, Table of Contents etc.